# How to fix this "Running schema recurring.Unique constraint violation found"

Tags: magento2, install-script

How to fix this error
`"Running schema recurring.Unique constraint violation found"`.

This statement occurs when I used upgrade command of Magento 2 model upgradation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Running schema recurring.Unique constraint violation found"** this occurs if there is **duplicate entry in any table of project db** and high probability to occur this problem is when you export db and then import,if db is not export completely or correctly.

so the solution is just export db again correctly and import

**and if you created tables then define at least one field as unique value in each table**

Answer (score 8):

To see the actual error, you need to run the data upgrade command on it's own:

`php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade`

And suddenly, after many hours of searching and debugging one gets to see the actual error, which in my case looked like this:

> In AbstractDb.php line 426:
>
> Unique constraint violation found
>
> In Mysql.php line 588:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
>   entry 'saferpaycw_transaction-0' for key
>   'SALES_SEQUENCE_META_ENTITY_TYPE_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `sales_sequence_meta` (`entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_   table`)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?)
>
> In Pdo.php line 235:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
>   entry 'saferpaycw_transaction-0' for key
>   'SALES_SEQUENCE_META_ENTITY_TYPE_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `sales_sequence_meta` (`entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_   table`)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?)
>
> In Pdo.php line 228:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
>   entry 'saferpaycw_transaction-0' for key
>   'SALES_SEQUENCE_META_ENTITY_TYPE_STORE_ID'