# How to solve Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry in sales_sequence_meta table when running setup:upgrade command?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I have the same problem as this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255003/106058

But I can't comment on his answer directly so here I am.

I'm using Magento 2.3.3. I ran `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and got `Unique constraint violation found` after the `Running data recurring...` message. So, I ran `bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade` and got this error message below:

```
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Running data recurring...
In AbstractDb.php line 427:

  Unique constraint violation found


In Mysql.php line 593:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'order-0' for key 'MG2_SALES_SEQUENCE_META_ENTITY_TYPE_STORE_ID', query was: INSE
  RT INTO `mg2_sales_sequence_meta` (`entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)


In Mysql.php line 110:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'order-0' for key 'MG2_SALES_SEQUENCE_META_ENTITY_TYPE_STORE_ID', query was: INSE
  RT INTO `mg2_sales_sequence_meta` (`entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)


In Mysql.php line 91:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'order-0' for key 'MG2_SALES_SEQUENCE_META_ENTITY_TYPE_STORE_ID'


setup:db-data:upgrade [--magento-init-params MAGENTO-INIT-PARAMS]
```

I tried deleting the existing records on the table (the error occurs only with the records where the `store_id` column is `0`) but it still showed the same error message. I even tried dropping the `sales_sequence_meta` and `sales_sequence_profile` tables of the Sales Sequence module and reran the upgrade command. It re-created the tables but still got the same error message.

Any idea on how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by truncating both the `sales_sequence_meta` and `sales_sequence_profile` tables and run the `bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade` command.

I ran the command before but thought that it differs from the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command which always failed when reaches the `SalesSequence` module. Then I found [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364254/6734629) which affirm that it's going to work so I followed along.

Also, the admin page can't be accessed since there was an error about missing class which the `bin/magento setup:di:compile` didn't help. Turned out it was a files permission issue not related to the upgrade command.